# Projecta are preserved under $r\Sigma_{n+1}$ embeddings which are witnessed by standard parameters

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

My question arises from the theorem $8.7$ of the fine structure article in the handbook of set theory. In order to prove the last claim of the theorem, I am proving something a little bit stronger, and I would like to know if it's correct or not.

So let $M$ be acceptable, $E$ some $(\kappa, \nu)$-extender over $M$. Let $n < \omega$ be such that $\rho_n(M) > \sigma(E)$. Suppose that $M$ is $n$-sound and $(n+1)$-solid and let $N = \mbox{Ult}_n(M;E)$ and $\pi:M \rightarrow N$ be the $r\Sigma_{n+1}$ ultrapower map given by $E$. Assume that $N$ is transitive and $\pi(p_{n+1}(M)) \in P^{n+1}_N$.

So we want to show that $\pi$ is an $n$-embedding, $N$ is $(n+1)$-solid and that $\pi(p_{n+1}(M)) = p_{n+1}(N)$. Now I can say that I understand all of the proof, except for the part that we should show that $\pi(\rho_k(M)) = \rho_k(N)$ for $k < n$, and so I tried to prove it, but what I ended up showing was $\pi(\rho_k(M)) = \rho_k(N)$ for $k \le n$; i.e. we also have the equality at the $n$-th projectum.

My argument goes like this: Since we have already shown that $\pi$ is $r\Sigma_{n+1}$ elementary, let $k \le n$, we know that $$\pi_{k-1} = \pi|H^M_{\rho_{k-1}(M)}:M^{k-1} \rightarrow N^{k-1},$$ is at least $\Sigma_{2}$ elementary (in fact it's $\Sigma_{n-k+2}$ elementary). First note that $\rho_k(M) = \rho_1(M^{k-1})$ and $\rho_k(N) = \rho_1(N^{k-1})$; and $p_k(M)(k-1) = p_1(M^{k-1})$ and $p_k(N)(k-1) = p_1(N^{k-1})$. And so by $\pi(p_{n+1}(M)) = p_{n+1}(N)$, we have $\pi_{k-1}(p_1(M^{k-1})) = p_1(N^{k-1})$. Now note that we have $$M^{k-1} \models \forall\alpha<\rho_k(M)\exists A\forall \xi< \alpha(\varphi(\xi, p_k(M)(k-1)) \longleftrightarrow \xi \in A),$$
for every $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$ and since the above formula is $\Sigma_2$, we also have:
$$N^{k-1} \models \forall\alpha<\pi_{k-1}(\rho_k(M))\exists A\forall \xi< \alpha(\varphi(\xi, \pi_{k-1}(p_k(M)(k-1))) \longleftrightarrow \xi \in A),
\\
\Leftrightarrow N^{k-1} \models \forall\alpha<\pi_{k-1}(\rho_k(M))\exists A\forall \xi< \alpha(\varphi(\xi, p_k(N)(k-1)) \longleftrightarrow \xi \in A),
$$
for every $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$. So we can deduce $\pi_{k-1}(\rho_k(M)) \le \rho_k(N)$. To see that $\pi_{k-1}(\rho_k(M)) \ge \rho_k(N)$, let $A \in \Sigma^{M^{k-1}}_1(\{p_k(M)(k-1)\})$ be a subset of $\rho_k(M)$, such that $A \not \in M^{k-1}$, which is defined by the $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi(x,y)$. And so $$M^{k-1} \models \neg\exists B\forall \xi< \rho_k(M)(\varphi(\xi, p_k(M)(k-1)) \longleftrightarrow \xi \in B),$$
and because the above formula is $\Pi_2$, we have
$$N^{k-1} \models \neg\exists B\forall \xi< \pi_{k-1}(\rho_k(M))(\varphi(\xi, \pi_{k-1}(p_k(M)(k-1))) \longleftrightarrow \xi \in B).$$
And so $\pi_{k-1}(\rho_k(M)) \ge \rho_k(N)$ and so we have equality. Doing this for every $k \le n$, we have $\pi(\rho_k(M)) = \rho_k(N)$. Now my proof also gives $\pi(\rho_n(M)) = \rho_n(N)$, which isn't stated in the theorem and I wonder if it's wrong. I would appreciate any corrections and explanations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\pi$ needn't preserve $\rho_n$. (And there is a problem in your argument, when you argue that $\pi(\rho_k^M)\leq\rho_k^N$ (particularly in the $k=n$ case); how is that formula $\Sigma_2$?)

E.g. suppose $M$ is $1$-sound and let $\rho=\rho_1^M$. Suppose $\rho<\mathrm{OR}^M$
and $\rho$ is singular with measurable cofinality in $M$ and let $E$ be an $M$-measure with $\mathrm{crit}(E)=\kappa$. Let $N=\mathrm{Ult}_1(M,E)$ and $\pi:M\to N$ the ultrapower map. Then $\pi$ is discontinuous at $\rho$. But $\rho_1^N=\sup\pi``\rho_1^M$, by standard theorems. So $\rho_1^N<\pi(\rho_1^M)$.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I still don't see the precise error in my reasoning. Since the only unbounded quantifier is $\exists A$ and the rest are bounded and the equivalence is of the form $\Sigma_1 \leftrightarrow \Sigma_0$ and since we are in $M^{n-1}$, we can use $\rho_n$ and $p_1(M^{n-1})$ as parameters; these facts combined, make it $\Sigma_2$, no?

Comment: Oh, I just realized; is it because the first $\forall \alpha<\rho_n(M)$ can't be interchanged with $\exists A$ because then we would have the sequence $\langle A_\alpha:\alpha<\rho_n\rangle$ and so we would have it's union and it would be a contradiction, and so the first quantifier is "unbounded"? [But we would have no problem for $k<n$, since it would be $\Pi_3$ and the embeddings do preserve $\Pi_3$ formulas, right?]

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Right, interchanging them gives a non-equivalent formula. I only see that the formula is $\Pi_4$; the inner part ("$\forall\xi<\alpha[\text{equivalence}]$") is $\Pi_2$ (it doesn't help that $\forall\xi<\alpha$ is bounded). However, it suffices to have the inner part just assert that $A$ is a generalized witness (i.e. "$\forall\xi<\alpha$, if $\varphi(\xi)$ holds then $\xi\in A$"), which is $\Pi_1$, and then the overall formula becomes $\Pi_3$. (That is, assuming that $N$ is also $k$-sound and $\pi$ preserves the lower fine structure and $p_k$, then $\pi(\rho_k^M)\leq\rho_k^N$.)

Comment: Ok, Thanks! But I don't see how the generalized witness may help. Because at that point we might as well take $A = \alpha$. And I think we may interchange $\forall \xi < \alpha$ with the inner quantifier for $\varphi$, as we do have the approximations $\langle A_\xi: \xi < \alpha\rangle$ for $\alpha < \rho_n$ inside $M^{n-1}$, no?

Comment: Ah, right, sorry, it should assert some extra properties for $A$, say $A$ is a consistent theory, closed under logical implication, containing the formula "I am a J-structure". (Or to make it a little simpler, you can assert that there is a J-structure $\bar{M}$, and $A$ is the theory of $\bar{M}$.) I'm not sure what you mean in the question about interchanging the inner quantifier...

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean, but I need to check the details to make it more precise, thanks. What I meant was that if $\varphi = \exists x \psi$, we may rewrite the $\forall \xi<\alpha (\xi \in A \rightarrow \varphi(\xi))$ as $\exists X \forall (\xi, x) \in X( \xi \in A \rightarrow \psi(\xi, x))$. Here $X$ is the set of tuples $(\xi, x)$ such that $\xi <\alpha$ and $x$ is a $<_M$-minimal witness to $\varphi=\exists x \psi$ and since $\alpha<\rho_n$ and $\psi$ is $\Sigma_0$, $X$ lives in $M^{n-1}$ and thus this rewritten form is equivalent to the first.